# Bash: Get file name under different directories

Tags: bash, file

```
# tree system/
system/
├── cat1
│   └── id1
├── cat5
│   └── id42
├── cat20
│   └── 59593
└── mumbry
    └── 3939
4 directories, 4 files
#
```

How to get directory name and file name? If possibly, how to use directory and file name on one for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to loop over the subdirectory and file name, a simple [wildcard expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) produces a list of those.

```
cd system
for file in */*; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

If you want to split them into directory and basename, there are built-in [text extraction facilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in the shell:

```
for file in */*; do
    echo "Directory: ${file%/*}"
    echo "Basename: ${file#*/}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The Directory and Basename substitutions from @tripleee are not working in my bash 4.2.25, the correct for loop is:

```
for file in */*; do
    # the match start from the end so you must invert the regexp
    echo "Directory: ${file%/*}" 

    # we must remove all the matches, not only the first
    echo "Basename: ${file##*/}" 
done
```

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: I can't comment to tripleee, I don't have 50 reputation points.